# Is it possible to make a generic method out of this, or at least separate them?

Tags: c#

I'm using ImageProcessor in C# and I can't come up with a way to make a generic method out of its methods as to avoid writing the same code more than once.

Say, I have two methods, crop and resize.

```
 public Image Resize(Image image, int width, int height)
{
    // Create a Image to be returned after being scaled, call it resizedImage:
    Image resizedImage;
    // Create a Size for the image to be scaled to, call it size:
    var size = new Size(width, height);
    // Create an ImageFactory to process the image, call it imageFactory:
    using (var imageFactory = new ImageFactory(preserveExifData: true))
    {
        // Create a MemoryStream to temporarily store the processed image, call it imageStream:
        using (var imageStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Scale the image using the ImageProcessor library
            // Load the image to be resized, resize it and save it to the MemoryStream:
            imageFactory.Load(image)
                        .Resize(size)
                        .Save(imageStream);
            // Assign the processed image to the previously declared resizedImage:
            resizedImage = Image.FromStream(imageStream);
        }
    }

    // Return the resized image:
    return resizedImage;
}
public Image Crop(Image image, float left, float top, float right, float bottom, bool isModePercentage = true)
{
    // Create a Image to be returned after being cropped, call it croppedImage:
    Image croppedImage;
    // Create a CropMode to specify what cropping method to use (Percentage or Pixels), call it cropMode
    // If isModePercentage = true we use CropMode.Percentage, otherwise use CropMode.Pixels:
    var cropMode = isModePercentage ? CropMode.Percentage : CropMode.Pixels;
    // Create a CropLayer to specify how and how much the image should be cropped, call it cropLayer:
    var cropLayer = new CropLayer(left, top, right, bottom, cropMode);
    // Create an ImageFactory to process the image, call it imageFactory:
    using (ImageFactory imageFactory = new ImageFactory(preserveExifData: true))
    {
        // Create a MemoryStream to temporarily store the processed image, call it imageStream:
        using (MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Crop the image using the ImageProcessor library
            // Load the image to be cropped, crop it and save it to the MemoryStream:
            imageFactory.Load(image)
                        .Crop(cropLayer)
                        .Save(imageStream);
            // Assign the processed image to the previously declared croppedImage:
            croppedImage = Image.FromStream(imageStream);
        }
    }
    // Return the cropped image:
    return croppedImage;
}
```

How can I avoid having to instantiate imagefactory and memory stream multiple times, reducing the size of my methods and avoid to write the same code twice?

Comment: Your title should state what your code does, not what you want out of a review. Please read the relevant Help pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I kept looking into this and discovered an answer that might be better than the one I previously accepted

```
    public Image ProcessImage(Image image, Func<ImageFactory, ImageFactory> process)
    {
        using (var imageFactory = new ImageFactory(preserveExifData: true))
        {
            using (var imageStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ImageFactory loadResult = imageFactory.Load(image);
                ImageFactory processResult = process(loadResult);
                processResult.Save(imageStream);

                imageStream.Position = 0;
                return Image.FromStream(imageStream);
            }
        }
    }
    // And then get the result like so //////////////////////////////////
    var resultResize =_imageEditor.ProcessImage(_image, im => im.Resize(size));
    var resultRotate =_imageEditor.ProcessImage(_image, im => im.Rotate(degrees));
```

I think this looks way cleaner like this - and it's super short.

I don't really want to accept my own answer but unless someone comes up with a reason this is wrong/bad I'll keep it like this for now.

Comment: I thought of doing something like that, don't know why I decided it will be too much effort.  What good about this implementation is that you can chain how much operations that you want.  Well done! 

Comment: imageStream.Position = 0; This line dide exist in the original implementation, I wonder why you added it.

Comment: Please make sure returning from inside the using is ok in terms of releasing the resource. In the original implementation you didn't have return inside the using.

Comment: @shanif I'm glad I managed to do something clean, didn't know about Func<> and lambda expressions before this and was a good learning experience. The imageStream.Position I took from another answer somewhere but tbh I'm not sure anymore why. Regarding returning inside the using, it's OK because it's essentially a try/finally block, so even if I return "inside the try" it will still run the "finally". Thanks again for your review!

Answer (score 3):

Well, it works well, but as you said, it can be optimized

#### Review:

You are commenting each line which is not good, only comment meaningful code sections. Commonly the names of the functions and variables you are calling is intuitive enough to know how the code is working. When it is insufficient then it is the moment to comment.

#### Refactoring:

You may create two class fields (`ImageFactory`,`MemoryStream`) and work with these.

```cs
private ImageFactory imageFactory;
private MemoryStream imageStream;

public [ClassName]() //the constructor if doubts
{
    imageFactory = ImageFactory(preserveExifData: true);
    imageStream = MemoryStream();
}

public Image Resize(Image image, int width, int height)
{
    imageFactory.Load(image).Resize(new Size(width, height)).Save(imageStream);
    return Image.FromStream(imageStream);
}

public Image Crop(Image image, float left, float top, float right, float bottom,
    bool isModePercentage = true)
{
    var cropMode = isModePercentage ? CropMode.Percentage : CropMode.Pixels;
    var cropLayer = new CropLayer(left, top, right, bottom, cropMode);

    imageFactory.Load(image).Crop(cropLayer).Save(imageStream);

    return Image.FromStream(imageStream);
}
```

Hope it has been helpful.

Comment: Disposing imageStream and imageFactory is missing.

Comment: @shanif could you check the answer I posted and tell me what you think about it? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Refactor

I extracted the common code to functions.

```cs
private ImageFactory CreateImageFactory(Image image)
{
    var imageFactory = new ImageFactory(preserveExifData: true) );
    return imageFactory.Load(image);
}

private static Image GetImage(this ImageFactory imageFactory)
{
    Image res;
    using (var imageStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        res = Image.FromStream(imageStream);
    }

    return res;
}

public Image Resize(Image image, int width, int height)
{
    Image resizedImage;
    var size = new Size(width, height);
    using (var imageFactory = CreateImageFactory(image))
    {       
        resizedImage = imageFactory.Resize(size).GetImage();
    }

    return resizedImage;
}

public Image Crop(Image image, float left, float top, float right, float bottom, bool isModePercentage = true)
{
    Image croppedImage;
    var cropMode = isModePercentage ? CropMode.Percentage : CropMode.Pixels;
    var cropLayer = new CropLayer(left, top, right, bottom, cropMode);
    using (var imageFactory = CreateImageFactory(image))
    {       
        croppedImage = imageFactory.Crop(cropLayer).GetImage();
    }
    return croppedImage;
}
```

### Code Review

As said before you commenting each line while your code is readable and speak for itself.

Some people consider **comments** as a **code smell**.

For example, while refactoring the code, it was very easy to lose the connection between the code the corresponding comment.

Besides that I think your code is readable, you have good names and it easy to understand.